# Backbonejs, "Object #<Object> has no method apply" when setting model attribute inside a Collections.each

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I made and initialized my model with the "change:status" event like this

```
Box = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.on('change:status', this.changed, this);
    },
    changed: function() {
      $('.changed').text('I changed'); // Testing if the 'change:status' is fired
    }
});
```

My Box collections is setup this way

```
BoxList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Box,
    initialize: function() {
       this.on('add', this.addOne, this);
       socket.on('box-status-change', this.boxStatusChanged, this);
    },
    boxStatusChanged: function(box) {
        Boxes.each(function(model) {
          if(model.get('changed') == box.changed) {
            model.set({status: 'changed'});
          }
        });
    },
    addOne: function.... // Some code removed
});

Boxes = new BoxList();
```

Checking in Chromes web developer tools, the attribute `status` was set to `changed` properly but an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'` occured. The `change:title` event of the model was not fired. Is there something I miss when adding the event to the model?

By the way, I'm using the *backbone-iosync.js* for the `Backbone.sync` method...

Comment: please post how the model and collection is setup btw instead `if(model.toJSON().changed == true)` why not `if(model.get("changed")){`

Comment: Which is the _code line_ of your code where the errors occurred?

Comment: @Deeptechtons thx for the advice on model.get("changed"), I already included the setup code..

Comment: @fguillen the error points to backbone-min.js, although the line 'model.set({status: 'changed'})' is also pointed in the error stack.

Comment: I switched to the unminified version of backbone.js and I see the error is pointing to line 163

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone uses an internal attribute called changed on models:

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changed

> **changed** *model.changed*
>   The changed property is the internal hash containing all the
>   attributes that have changed since the last "change" event was
>   triggered. Please do not update changed directly. Its state is
>   maintained internally by set and change. A copy of changed can be
>   acquired from changedAttributes.

Rename your callback to something else and that works

```
Box = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      this.on('change:status', this.changedState, this);
    },
    changedState: function() {
      console.log('changed');
    }
});
```

A Fiddle to reproduce your problem http://jsfiddle.net/NrTPk/ and a modified version http://jsfiddle.net/NrTPk/1/

Comment: I knew there was someone in the same road than me ;)

Comment: @James Going backwards. Your code should have worked, so probably a conflict. I checked the source code and then the docs to see if something was said about it.

Comment: Removing my answer due this is more complete.